# How does ffmpeg read stdin pipe?

Tags: python, python-2.7, ffmpeg, subprocess, pipe

I'm working on a Python script that generates an image sequence based on user real time remote interaction, and uses ffmpeg to compress and stream this image sequence over the network for the user to watch it.
As soon as an image is generated the script writes it to ffmpeg's stdin and this action is repeated inside a loop to form a video.

I was wondering what happens when ffmpeg is busy processing the previous image when I write to stdin.

- Does the .stdin.write() command block execution until ffmpeg finishes processing the previous image? (Consequence of the pipe buffer filling up)
- What's the buffer size of subprocess.PIPE?
- Is it editable?
- Is it possible to overwrite this buffer if it's full, instead of blocking execution?
- Does ffmpeg continually read it's input in a parallel process and buffers it until it's free to take care of it?
- If that's the case, what's the size of ffmpeg's input buffer and how can I change it?

I'm asking this because I want to fully understand how the data travels between Python and ffmpeg to reduce the latency to its minimum.

Here is the part of the code I'm using to start ffmpeg:

```
cmd = ['ffmpeg',
    '-f', 'rawvideo',
    '-s', '%dx%d'%(width, height),
    '-pix_fmt', 'rgba',
    '-r', '%d'%fps,
    '-i', '-',
    '-an',
    '-vcodec', 'libx264',
    '-tune', 'zerolatency',
    '-preset', 'ultrafast',
    '-bf', '0',
    '-f', 'mpegts',
    'udp://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxxx']

proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
```

And this is what I call inside a loop when I want to pass an image to ffmpeg:

```
proc.stdin.write(image)
```

Comment: Yes, `.stdin.write()` is a blocking call. Pipe buffer size is OS-dependent, and Python doesn't have any guarantees. No, the buffer size is not configurable -- this is why folks have traditionally used tools like `pv` or `bfr` to insert their own buffering in shell pipelines when needed.

Comment: ...most of the above doesn't require knowledge of ffmpeg *or* Python to answer, but just the UNIX FIFO construct.

Comment: (now, the question about how much buffering is done on ffmpeg's end -- **that** is configurable, but I'd argue that it's more a usage question than anything else)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I'm using this script in Windows, MacOS and Linux indistinctly

Comment: And there may be a way to handle the pipe behaviour from Python?

Comment: "Handle the pipe behavior"? Not clear what you mean by that at all. You can have a separate thread do the `sys.stdin.write()` call, or you can pass different arguments to `ffmpeg`.

Comment: By that I mean getting the pipe buffer size and/or changing it from Python

Comment: Can't do that. And it's typically something small enough that it doesn't matter -- certainly not on the scale of data used for video encoding. This is why, as I mentioned above, tools like [`pv`](http://www.ivarch.com/programs/pv.shtml) or [`bfr`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/bfr) are popular.

Comment: about ffmpeg's buffer size, I know there is a buffer parameter, but the documentation usually refers to it as an output buffer (the size people assigns to this is usually relative to the output image size) but I'm talking about an input buffer, before the image is processed

Comment: (well -- you *can* change the pipe buffer size on Linux with `F_SETPIPE_SZ`, but since you need to work across three separate operating systems, that's not something likely to be helpful).

Comment: ...see https://github.com/wal-e/wal-e/blob/master/wal_e/pipebuf.py#L18 for an example of it being done.